# なぜ PureScript の Data.Array.ST の STArray には length がないのですか？

Tags: purescript

なぜ PureScript の Data.Array.ST の `STArray` には `length` がないのですか？

現状は↓のように `unsafeFreeze` で `STArray` を `Array` にしたあと `Array` の `length` で取得しています。

```
module Main
  ( main
  ) where

import Prelude

import Control.Monad.ST as ST
import Data.Array as Array
import Data.Array.ST as STArray
import Effect (Effect)
import Effect.Console as Console

main :: Effect Unit
main = Console.logShow $ ST.run do
  sta <- STArray.empty
  a <- STArray.unsafeFreeze sta
  pure (Array.length a)
```

もっと良い方法があれば教えてください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

こんにちは。
STArrayの長さが変化するオペレーションというと`push`と`pushAll`だと思いますが、これは評価結果としてlength :: Intを返します。ほとんどの場合これで用は足りるということだと思います。
Emptyは暗黙的に0であり、Arrayからの変換であれば元のArrayのlengthを取ればよく、`splice`は切り抜いたArrayを返すのでこれも直接lengthが取れます。